# How to close [No Name] buffer without closing vim?

Tags: vim

Please, see the screenshot:

[image]

After `:help some-page` I opened new unnamed buffer by `:new`. Now I want to close it (hence bottom window), but when I press `^Wq` (which should close the focused window) it closes vim at all! What's wrong here?

Comment: Does `:bd[elete]` work? Have you tried without a vimrc (`vim -u NONE -U NONE file`)?

Comment: The same. The only `:close` work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim quits when you close the `[No Name]` buffer because it's the last listed buffer (see `:ls` and `:ls!`, also `:h unlisted-buffers` for more info on unlisted buffers).

You can use `:clo[se]` (or `^Wc`), which simply removes the current window (you'll then have the help window in the entire pane).

Answer (score 3):

From `:h ^wq`:

> Quit current window.  When quitting the last window (not counting a help window), exit Vim.

It seems that you're using `^wq` while the bottom window is selected, and that will leave only a help window, thus exiting vim.

Select the help window with `^ww` or similar, and then do `^wq`.

Another alternative is to use `:bd[delete]` or `:clo[se]`.